# Как отправить временный файл на другой сервис

Tags: php, файлы, api

У меня дешевый хостинг, места для изображений нет. Собираюсь использовать сторонний сервис для хранения изображений. Для загрузки нужна полная ссылка на изображение. Могу ли я отправить временный файл (из массива $_FILES) на сторонний хостинг, и может ли он нормально скачать изобрежение? И как из [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpXPfb1W сделать полную ссылку?

Comment: нет, нельзя. никак. Либо этот "сторонний сервис" позволяет загружать к себе файлы без ссылок, либо сначала сохранять на этом.

Comment: @Ипатьев но там же есть путь, и файл удаляется только после завершения скрипта

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths

Comment: @Ипатьев понял, спасибо)